# how to check if a row or column is already present in the table while inserting or updating the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am building a project in which I access database tables, insert and update rows and columns into the table.

I am updating a table in the database using a `GridView`, using which I am adding new column every time to another table.

My code on button_Click is:

```
com = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Location_Profile_Master ADD " + LocProName.Text + " int", con);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                string Pro_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;

                for (int i = 1; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    int n = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[i + 1].Text);
                    //short n = 0;
                    //if (Int16.TryParse(row.Cells[i + 1].Text, out n))
                    //{
                        com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Location_Profile_Master SET " + LocProName.Text + "='" + n + "' WHERE Profile_Name='" + Pro_Name.ToString().Trim() + "' ", con);
                        con.Open();
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    //}
                }

            }
```

Therefore while adding the column and its values, I want to check if that column name is already present in the database, if not present I want to check if the column values is already present in the database. User should be notified that it column is already present in the data base.

Also while I am inserting a row, I want to know if that row is already present in the table.

kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can read schema informations in MS SQL-Server in the [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) directly or you can use `DataReader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly)` to retrieve the schema informations of a given table:

```
DataTable schema;
using (var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    var getSchemaSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tableName);
    using (var schemaCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(getSchemaSql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}
```

and then something similar to this:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < schema.Rows.Count; rowIndex ++)
{
    DataRow schemaRow = schema.Rows[rowIndex];
    String columnName = schemaRow.Field<String>("ColumnName");
    Type dataType = schemaRow.Field<Type>("DataType");
    Int32 columnSize = schemaRow.Field<Int32>("ColumnSize");
    if (dataType.FullName == "System.String")
    {
        // ...
    } 
 }
```

or, if you simply want to check if a given column name exists in that table:

```
String colName = "Column1";
bool exists = schema.AsEnumerable()
                    .Any(r => r.Field<String>("ColumnName") == colName);
```

if you want to know if a row already exists, you could use it's primary-key/identifier and [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) in sql:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Location_Profile_Master WHERE PROFILE_NAME=@ProfileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be better of making a stored procedure for this sort of things like this:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Location_Profile_Master' 
              AND Column_Name = @columnParam) 
BEGIN
    -- The column exists
END
ELSE
    -- The column doesn't exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MS SQL Server. Try this code to check if the column exists and inside it verifies if the row exists:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE Name = N'columnName'  
            AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Location_Profile_Master'))
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Profile_Name FROM Location_Profile_Master WHERE Profile_Name = @yourValue)
    BEGIN
        --value exists
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all an advice: use parameters instead of value `"'" + "'"`, because it is sensitive againts SQL Injection.

To check in the database that a column is exists or not you can use:

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN COL_LENGTH('tableName', 'columnName') IS NOT NULL 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isExists
```

This will give you a 0 even if the table is not exists in the database